# Keep getting the steam errors [missing file privileges] and [disk write error]

Tags: steam, windows-11

Every time I try to update or install a game, it gives me either one of these errors:

- missing file privileges
- disk write error

I have tried most of the fixes that I found which include:

- Repairing steam library folder(didn't work)
- Closing the igfxEm Module from the task manager(didn't work)
- Verifying the integrity of the game(didn't work)
- Running Steam with Administrator privileges(worked)
- Changing download region(didn't work)
- Clearing out temporary download cache(didn't work)
- Also tried chkdsk D: /F /R /B (didn't work)

The only one that has worked was making steam run as an administrator, which is great, but I am wondering why that makes it work and what is causing this issue in the first place since my steam was working perfectly before. How come it's acting up now?

Comment: Well, it makes sense for "file priviledge" errors to go away when you have adming priviledges. As for what caused it, we can't really answer that without more information. Are you using Steam on Windows, Mac, Linux? Did something happen before Steam stopped working? Did you change the location where Steam installs its games? Did you move games that have been already installed? Try to give us as much information and be as specific as you can.

Comment: I am on windows 11 nothing happened that would cause this my steam is on a different drive from where my games are but that's never been an issue until now and I haven't moved anything around

Comment: What fixes did you try? Without knowing, they're likely to be suggested again. I see suggestions including clearing Steam's download cache, changing download settings to update region, verify game integrity, "Steam->Settings->Storage->Steam Library Folders->3-dot menu by folder->Repair", and "just reinstall". One more suggestion to stop the Intel graphics card process, but that seems dumb and like it would be temporary.